# Change tempo and stretch pattern

Tags: fl-studio

I have a drum pattern in FL studio 20. I want to multiply the tempo by factor of 2 and stretch the drum pattern by factor of two as well (so that it doesn't become 2x faster and keeps the pace).

Is it possible?
I don't want to rewrite the drum pattern.

Comment: Is this drum pattern a sequence of MIDI notes corresponding to each drum hit, or is it an audio recording of a drum pattern (or a combination of both)?

Comment: I can answer this, but I need clarification (see my above comment)

Answer (score 0):

Yes. The magic is called editing.

It‘s simple. View the drum pattern. When it repeats after 1 bar, you‘ll double it to 2, 2 bars to 4 and so on.

Next, recreate the pattern AND make each duration twice as long. So durations needing 1 field become 2 fields (beats), 2 become 4 in time and so on.

Repeat for all voices.

It‘s easier to do than to note down here ;-)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to double the tempo while keeping the drum pattern at the same pace. FL Studio already does this by default, but to make sure, you can open the sampler, on the right side near the top, there is a selection next to the Time knob. Make sure it says resample, and the speed wont change as the tempo does.